# Getting Count based on values of multiple rows of the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to database.
    Say that if I have table like below:

```
PHeader AHeader IHeader

p1       a1      0

p1       a1      2

p1       a1      3

p1       a2      0

p1       a3      0

p1       a4      0

p1       a4      2

p1       a4      3

p2       a5      0
```

The expected output is :

```
PHeader BCount  TCount


p1          2    2

p2          0    1
```

BCount: is for the given  PHeader and AHeader Value, if the IHeader values has all the values of (0,2 &3) then BCount value of PHeader is increased by  1 , Since for the p1 it has a1 & a4 with all the vaues of 0,2 & 3 as IHeader Values the BCount for p1 is given as 2

TCount: is for  given  given PHeader and AHeader value , if  IHeader value has only 0 but not 2 or 3, then TCount for the given PHeader is increased by 1. Hence the TCount for p1
    is given as 2.

Could you please give me tips in writing the query?

Comment: I'm sure you could make this question more confusing. I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this using two aggregations.  The inner one aggregates at the `pheader`, `aheader` level.  This counts the values that you are interested in.

The outer one applies the logic that you've described to these summaries:

```
select pheader,
       sum(ih_0 > 0 and ih_2 > 0 and ih_3 > 0) as bcount,
       sum(ih_0 > 0 and (ih_2 = 0 or ih_3 = 0)) as tcount
from (select pheader, aheader,
             sum(iheader = 0) as ih_0,
             sum(iheader = 2) as ih_2,
             sum(iheader = 3) as ih_3
      from table t
      group by pheader, aheader 
     ) pa
group by pheader;
```

EDIT:

The question is tagged MySQL.  The following will work in both databases:

```
select pheader,
       sum(case when ih_0 > 0 and ih_2 > 0 and ih_3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as bcount,
       sum(case when ih_0 > 0 and (ih_2 = 0 or ih_3 = 0) then 1 else 0 end) as tcount
from (select pheader, aheader,
             sum(case when iheader = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ih_0,
             sum(case when iheader = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ih_2,
             sum(case when iheader = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as ih_3
      from table t
      group by pheader, aheader 
     ) pa
group by pheader;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the quick reply.I am sure yours is correct answer. I am using Mircosoft SQL Server, it says incorrect syntax near '>' . Could you pls help me in getting the syntax right. Thanks for pointing in right direction anyhow.

Comment: Somehow I could not get the syntax right , but instead I used case when statement and got it right. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2844265 . . . I added that version in.  Your question is mis-tagged as MySQL, if you are really using SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks  One more extension to the problem is that for the given PHeader value , if the BCount Value is greater than 0, then I need to get the Maximum Aheader value which contributes towards  increase of BCount. So in the above use case: for P1 - (a1 & a4) contributes to increase in BCount . In that case I need to get a4 as  MaxAHeaderValueForPHeader. Is it possible to include in the same query? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check beloq sql query

```
SELECT 
PHeader ,
COUNT(*) as BCount  , --total 
SUM(CASE WHEN PHeader = 'p1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TCount
```

FROM 
    yourtablename
group by PHeader

Hope this will give you some idea.